# Unable to parse html file in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  
# Opening the html file
HTMLFile = open("index.html", "r")
  
# Reading the file
contents = HTMLFile.read()
  
# Creating a BeautifulSoup object and specifying the parser
S = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')

print (S.find_all(""))
```

What should I use in finding to parse the highlighted element in the picture below? Nothing seems to work.[image]

Comment: can you provide URL of website it will be easy to understand!

Comment: Bhavya Parikh: this is a static html genrated after running a test

Comment: The HTML does not look too long, you could add it to your question using the [edit] button, we would then be able to test your script. Also please explain what your aim/output would be once you locate the item

Answer (score 0):

Get the specific element and use `.nextSibling`. So here we'll find the `<button>` tag, then the `<i>` tag to get the nextSibling from there.

```
print (S.find('button').find('i').nextSibling)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since that `<button>` is present inside a `<li>` with an attribute `title="Passed"` select that `<li>` first and then the `<button>` element.

This is how you do it.

```py
# Select the <li>
list_item = soup.find('li', {'title': 'Passed'})

# Select the <button>
btn = list_item.find('button')

# print the btn's text
print(btn.text)
```